# Are there any difference between RSA_Sign() of NSS and RSA_sign() of Open SSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, nss

When i use the `RSA_Sign()` of `NSS` and `fips_rsa_sign_digest()` of Open SSL i get different signature value. Are there any difference in the functionality of these two? 
Same parameter/private key is input to these 2 functions with proper conversion for NSS and SSL.

Answer (score 0):

RSA signatures are created with a probabilistic signature scheme as defined in PKCS#1, e.g. RSASSA-PSS, because plain RSA is not secure against some attacks. PSS includes a random value (salt). You should see a different outcome every time.